# "Empirical probability approaches Classical probability when no. of trials $\to \infty$"?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

What does the following mean?:

> Empirical probability approaches Classical probability when the number of trials approaches infinity.

Suppose I toss an unbiased coin million times and 750 thousand times it's heads. Now we're going towards infinity. So if this empirical probability actually approaches the classical one then chances should be in favor of me getting tails as the 1000001th outcome. But that isn't true. There's still the same 50% chance of having tails on the next toss.

Comment: Where does this statement come from?  It is at best sloppy and at worst incorrect.

Comment: @Paul I read it in my school textbook.

Comment: To understand what exactly the following means you need a notion of convergence used in probability theory such as convergence in probability. Also if you toss a fair coin 1 million times you will **never** get 75000 Heads or less because this event has negligible probability/

Comment: @kludg I actually meant 750 heads. I've edited it. And theoretically it $can$ happen.

Comment: 750000 heads or more will *never* happen too, because the probability again is negligible. Actually any number of heads in 1 million tosses of a fair coin that you can obtain in a real experiment will be much much closer to 500000 than you can imagine, but to be more exact you need to know normal distribution and central limit theorem.

Comment: @kludg Again I'm saying $theoretically$ it $can$ happen. If it doesn't happen in first million tosses (which it surely won't) then go for another million tosses. Or maybe hire a 100 trillion people and they all toss million times. It'll happen with at least one of them. There's no point in arguing that low probability things never happen.

Comment: The statement in the question might be a quite sloppy version of the result that, if $(X_n)$ is i.i.d. and integrable then the empirical mean $$\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nX_k$$ almost surely converges to the theoretical mean $$E(X_1)$$ when $n\to\infty$. This is called "law of large numbers" and implies that the proportion of heads after $n$ independent throws of a fair coin converges almost surely to $\frac12$. (Add here one or two sentences explaining why any author transforming the above into any statement similar to the one in the question should be shot on sight.)

Answer (score 2):

The probability of tails on any toss of the fair coin is always 0.50. For a given $N$ tosses there will probably be an imbalance of heads and tails, but from that point forward the expectation is an equal number of each, so any finite imbalance for $N < \infty$ will tend to be averaged out as $N \rightarrow \infty$, such that $H/(H+T) \rightarrow 0.5$. The absolute difference of heads vs. tails will tend to grow though.

Comment: "The absolute difference of heads vs. tails will tend to grow though" Hmmm... Nonnegative sequences that are at zero infinitely many times can hardly be said to "grow".

Comment: @Did I think it will grow. You certainly can't expect the difference to be zero when we have too many tosses. In fact, in a billion tosses, it won't be a surprise if there are 10 thousand more heads than tails. Similarly in trillion tosses the difference might be in millions and still the coin will be unbiased. It will be the difference to toss ratio that will be small.

Comment: Maybe a better way to put it is that the expected value of the difference as a function of $N$ will grow as $N \rightarrow \infty$. Thus "tend."

Comment: @Dove No. Once again, if $D_n$ is the difference at time $n$, then $\{n\mid D_n=0\}$ is almost surely infinite hence $P(D_n\to\infty)=0$.

Comment: @JoeKnapp Yes, as soon as you add "expected" to the pot, this becomes true.